# while the select editoption posts the value (or id) of the selected list item, autocomplete posts the label - i need id posted

Tags: jqgrid, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

While both autocomplete and select in jqgrid editform place the selected label into the cell, select will place the value (id) in the postdata array where autocomplete will place the label into the postdata array.

is there a way to get the editoption's autocomplete to post the item value (id) instead of the label?

here is the jqgrid code segment i'm using autocomplete in...

```
$('#tab3-grid').jqGrid({
   colNames:['Workorder', 'wo.CUID',.....],
   colModel:[  
      .
      .
      .  
      {name:'wo.CUID', index:'cu.LastName', width:120, fixed:true, align:'center', sortable:true, editable:true, edittype:'text',
         editoptions:{dataInit:function(el){$(el).autocomplete({ source: 'php/customer-ac-script.php' 
                                                              , minLength: 1

                                                             })
                                          }
                    },
         formoptions:{rowpos: 1, label:'Customer', elmprefix:'* '},
         editrules:{required:true}
      },
      .
      .
      .
$('#tab3-grid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#tab3-pager',
   {view:true, closeOnEscape:true, cloneToTop:true}, // general parameters that apply to all navigation options below.
   {jqModal:true, navkeys:[true,38,40], savekey:[true,13]}, // edit options.
   {jqModal:true, navkeys:[true,38,40], savekey:[true,13], reloadAfterSubmit:false, afterSubmit: addRecordID}, // add options.
   {jqModal:true, afterSubmit: serverMessage}, // del options.
   {jqModal:true}, // search options.
   {jqModal:true, navkeys:[true,38,40]} // view options.
);
```

The php code segment:

```
// construct autocomplete select.
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $output[$i][$crudConfig['id']]    = $row['CUID'];
   $output[$i][$crudConfig['value']] = $row['LastName'];
   logMsg(__LINE__,'I','cu.CUID: '.$row['CUID'].', cu.LastName: '.$row['LastName']);

   $i++;
}

// encode to json format and send output back to jqGrid table.
echo json_encode($output);
logMsg(__LINE__,'I','Send json output back to jqGrid table: '.json_encode($output));
```

Would it be as simple as calling a function under the autocomplete select event or the grid before or after editform submit?

Also, i noticed this note in the jqgrid doc's for datainit: that says...

> Note: Some plugins require the position of the element in the DOM and
>   since this event is raised before inserting the element into the DOM
>   you can use a setTimeout function to accomplish the desired action.

Would the lack of including the settimeout function be causing the problem?

Comment: Could you describe your question more exactly? For example which format has the data which return 'php/customer-ac-script.php'. jQuery UI Autocomplete allow you to have full control between the labels which will be displayed in the context menu of autocomplete and the values which will be inserted in the `<input>` control after the user choose the item. So you should just define exactly the format of input data and implement `select` and probably `_renderItem`.

Comment: what i'm saying is that the jquery autocomplete attached to datainit: does function, but when the editform is submitted, the postdata array contains the autocomplete display text not the id associated with it. I have added the php code segment to the original post to show you what jqgrid is getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server code which provide the JSON response on the autocomplete request has `id` and `value` properties. On the other side the standard behavior of jQuery UI Autocomplete is to use `label` and `value` properties (see "Datamodel" in the [documentation](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137709/Autocomplete)). The value of `label` property (if any exist) will be used to display in the contextmenu. The value of `value` property will be placed in the `<input>` field after the user choose the item from the contextmenu. The value of `label` property can has HTML markup, but the value of `value` property must be the text.

So I see the problem as pure problem of the usage of jQuery UI Autocomplete independent on jqGrid. If I understand correct your question you can solve your problem by modification your server side code.

Comment: Yes, i learned from the jqgrid forum today that jqgrid does not alter the functionality of jquery autocomplete. Also, i looked at the datamodel link you offered.  It looks like the server side code is constructing and sending the correct json string.  So I guess my question now is... what inserts the label value into the postdata array at the time time the editform is submitted?  Is it autocomplete or the editform?

Comment: @NelsonM: In you current code the server produce `'id'` and `'value'` property instead of `'value'` and `'label'`. Because jQuery UI Autocomplete don't find `label` property it uses `value` as the `label`. The `id` property will be ignored. To you should post `$row['CUID']` as the `value` property and `$row['LastName']` as the `label` property.

Comment: I am so sorry... i was confused when i studied the autocomplete page http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote . I noticed the value of the name/value pairs could be retrieved through an event like select using ui.item.id <-- and ui.item.value <-- as shown in the view source for remote datasource. So, i assumed that the names of the name/value pair where "id" and "value". I also thought the overview for ac was using the words label and value descriptively since the viewsource code was using "id" and "value".  The doc's should be written for dummies like me. again, sorry and thanks a lot.

Comment: I will also make better use of the jquery UI wiki you linked to.

Comment: @NelsonM: Sorry, I don't sure whether you solve the problem or not yet. Is it solved?

Comment: Yes - with regard to correct use of autocomplete and No - with what i need in the "term" parameter. In my case, the server side table contains numeric id's. I send the grid descriptive names of the id's.  If editform is submitted without focusing and selecting a label from the menu list, autocomplete will not fire and not populate the menu list. Autocomplete has only the contents of the grid row cell – the descriptive name of the table id.  Submitting editform will only give me a "term" containing a table id description and not the numeric id i need to update the server side table row.

Comment: I have to either …

1. create hidden grid id column to go along with the description column and get autocomplete to set the "ui.item.id" to the value in the id column associated with the currently displayed label.

2. have autocomplete fire when the editform is opened or the navkeys are used so an autocomplete search will be initiated with the string currently in the autocomplete search field.

I Hope result is auto selected label/value pair being available in the menu list so when the jqgrid editform is submitted, the "term" parameter will contain the actual id i need for table updates.

Answer (score 1):

Oleg's answer clarifying the data model for jquery UI's autocomplete, has allowed me to move forward and  understand that autocomplete has nothing to do with constructing and sending the postdata array to the server, jqgrid's editform handles it. With that knowledge, i was able to answer my original question and successfully integrate autocomplete into jqgrid.  So, in the interest of sharing, i'd like to show you all my motivation and solution.

By default, selecting a label from the autocomplete list put's the value of the selected label/value pair into the text box.  All the editform cares about when you submit is what's in the edit fields.  So when you submit the editform, the cell's postdata element value will again contain the value of the autocomplete text box.  But what if while wanting to post the value of the label/value pair, you want the label of the label/value pair displayed in the text box?  You have a problem!  How do you get the value of the label/value pair posted to the server?

Well, after spending a few days on it, it turns out to be quite simply.  While i'm sure there is more than one solution, here is mine:

1. add a hidden id column in the grid
2. define the select: and focus: events in the autocomplete function
3. in the select: function; insert the selected label into the text box (optional), disable the default behavior of autocomplete, then set the cell of the hidden column to the value of the selected label/value pair
4. in the focus: function; insert the selected label into the text box(optional), disable the default behavior of autocomplete
5. add an "onclickSubmit:" event to the navgrid edit options with function name something like "fixpostdata"
6. in the "fixpostdata" function; get the cell value of the hidden column and insert it into the postdata element associated with the cell.

The following are the grid and javascript code segments i used…

```
grid segments

{name:'wo_CUID', index:'wo_CUID', width: 70, hidden: true},
{name:'wo.CUID', index:'cu.LastName', width:120, sortable:true, editable:true,  edittype:'text',
   editoptions:{
      dataInit:function(el){ // el contains the id of the edit form input text box.
         $(el).autocomplete({

             source: 'php/customer-ac-script.php',
             minLength: 1,

             select: function(event, ui){event.preventDefault();
                  $(el).val(ui.item.label);
                  var rowid = $('#tab3-grid').getGridParam('selrow');

                   // set the hidden wo_CUID cell with selected value of the selected label.
                   $('#tab3-grid').jqGrid('setCell', rowid,'wo_CUID',ui.item.value);},

            focus: function(event, ui) {event.preventDefault();
                  $(el).val(ui.item.label);}
                                     })
                              }
                     },
   formoptions:{rowpos: 1, label:'Customer', elmprefix:'* '},
   editrules:{required:true}

},

.

.

$('#tab3-grid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#tab3-pager',
   {view:true, closeOnEscape:true, cloneToTop:true},
   {jqModal:true, navkeys:[false,38,40], onclickSubmit: fixpostdata}, // edit options.

.

.

javascript function

// define handler function for 'onclickSubmit' event.
var fixpostdata = function(params, postdata){
   var rowid = $('#tab3-grid').getGridParam('selrow');
   var value = $('#tab3-grid').jqGrid('getCell', rowid,'wo_CUID');

   postdata['wo.CUID'] = value;

   return;
}
```

The fixpostdata function fires when you submit the editform but befor the postdata array is sent to the server.  At this point you replace the cell's postdata element value with whatever you want.  In this case, the value of the label/value pair stored in the hidden column cell.  When the function returns, the modified postdata array is sent to the server.

Done!